# Sort alphabetically hash's values in array from STRIPE API / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, sorting

In rails 6.1.4, I want to display the :nickname of a Product in STRIPE in DESC order. I mean S, M, L on my VIEW page and not in a random way like Stripe give us.
In their https://stripe.com/docs/api it seems we couldn't make the request on an easy way.

For this, I query `@compositionsProduct = Stripe::Price.list(product: @composition.product)`. It returns me an Array of Hash in the `data` part:

```
    => #<Stripe::ListObject:0x3ff733e41c08> JSON: {
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {"id":"price_price1","object":"price","active":true,"billing_scheme":"per_unit","created":1635150421,"currency":"eur","livemode":false,"lookup_key":null,"metadata":{},"nickname":"L","product":"prod_prod1","recurring":null,"tax_behavior":"unspecified","tiers_mode":null,"transform_quantity":null,"type":"one_time","unit_amount":4500,"unit_amount_decimal":"4500"},
    {"id":"price_price2","object":"price","active":true,"billing_scheme":"per_unit","created":1635150421,"currency":"eur","livemode":false,"lookup_key":null,"metadata":{},"nickname":"S","product":"prod_prod1","recurring":null,"tax_behavior":"unspecified","tiers_mode":null,"transform_quantity":null,"type":"one_time","unit_amount":2500,"unit_amount_decimal":"2500"},
    {"id":"price_price3","object":"price","active":true,"billing_scheme":"per_unit","created":1635150421,"currency":"eur","livemode":false,"lookup_key":null,"metadata":{},"nickname":"M","product":"prod_prod1","recurring":null,"tax_behavior":"unspecified","tiers_mode":null,"transform_quantity":null,"type":"one_time","unit_amount":3500,"unit_amount_decimal":"3500"}
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "url": "/v1/prices"
}
```

I want to write something like this:
`Stripe::Price.list(product: @composition.product).sort_by([:nickname].reverse)` but it obviously doesn't work.

I can iterate over these 3 lines, but I need to `linked_to` them on their Price page respectively.

```
<% @compositionsProduct.map do |compoPrice| %>
  <%= link_to "#{compoPrice.nickname}", composition_path(compoPrice.id) %>
<% end %>
```

This is my farest point: `@compositionsProduct.sort_by { |hash| hash[:nickname]}` negative sign doesn't work, neither `.reverse`

What is the best way to `sort_by` alphabetically the values of a specific line in an array of hash?

Comment: List requests always respond is chronological order by object creation, most recent first. It's not random, it's just not what you need.

Comment: Well, I created prices for a product in a chronological order S, then M, then L. But sometimes I get S, M, L, sometimes L, M, S etc. I checked the created_at and the Price_id but it just throw random number. I have to do it manually for this simple needs

Comment: You you created them in the order S, M, L the list request should always return L, M, S, then. The most recently created should be listed first.

Answer (score 0):

`@compositionsProduct.sort_by { |hash| hash[:nickname] }.reverse` works very well.